# ¿Cómo pasar string a una colección?

Tags: array, string, colecciones, smalltalk

Si tengo un objeto que es un string:

```
col := 'jose,pablo,miguel'
```

Y quiero pasar `col` es una `OrderedCollection` con los tres elementos, ¿cómo lo haría?, ¿por ejemplo?:

```
col := 'jose,pablo,miguel'.
nombres := OrderedCollection new.
```

y ¿qué 'nombres' tenga tres elementos y descartar la coma?

Answer (score 0):

Esto depende un poco de en qué dialecto tengas que hacer la conversión. En Pharo, por ejemplo, donde existe el mensaje `split:` sería

```
$, split: 'jose,pablo,miguel'.
```

En Squeak podrías usar `splitBy:` de este modo

```
'jose,pablo,miguel' splitBy: ','
```

La diferencia es que este último responde un `Array`, mientras que el anterior una `OrderedCollection`.